# Get specific number of rows ordered by date for each key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a table from which i get data as follows:

```
val all = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","table")
 .select("key_name", "column1", "column2", "column3", "date")
 .as((i:String, p:String, e:String, c:Double, d:java.util.Date) => ((i), (c, p, e, d)))
```

Table is ordered by date. I want to fetch data in a way that for every key_name I will have specified number of records. I don't know if it's achievable in query to cassandra table or it should be done after data is loaded from table. For example I would like to have five latest records for each key_name grouped in some sort of sorted collection.

Comment: I'm not sure if the cassandra connector accepts pushdown on predicates. So you maybe want to load the data and then apply your action

Comment: There is a `spanByKey()` extra method exposed by the connector. You may be interested: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key

Comment: So if I use `spanByKey` data doesn't get shuffled (ordering is preserved) and i can get first five elements from the resulting array for each key and they will be five latest records?

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit on cluster column like below from the link

SELECT * FROM playlists WHERE id = 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204
  ORDER BY song_order DESC LIMIT 50;

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html

Comment: Yes but I would have to run this query for each key and I want to do it all in one to be more efficient.